# CCBReader not reading files

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, cocosbuilder

I am trying to update an old game from to cocos2d v2.2, but CCBReader is not able to read .ccbi files and ends up throwing as assertion failure with warning

> File not found: HomeScreen.ccbi

What happens is, all the ccbi files are ziped, when game launches the first time, following code is used to unzip all the CCScenes

```
[CCBReader unzipResources:@"ccb.zip"];
```

This was working with older code, I updated the cocos2d, CCBReader and SSZipArchive, code builds perfectly but then game crashes with the assertion failure.

**EDIT:**
I tried to search for files unzipped using iPhone explorer. I found that the normal resources (which are not zipped) are in .app folder and the zipped resources are unzipped in Library folder, can this be the cause for file not found?

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if I understood you properly, but I think that you should try to load .ccb files with CCBReader, not ccbi. Ccbi is compiled CocosBuilder interface file.